# How to add filters for alerts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-logging

[What field in the terraform `resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy"` added filters for google logging alerts?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWbC2.png)

Comment: The image snippet is maybe a little too cropped.  I can't tell which page in the console that comes from.  Maybe provide a link to the GCP documentation for the help page for the area that you wish to map to Terraform?   In the bit of the screen shot I did see, I did notice that there was a "preview" flag ... it may be that this function is beta at GCP and hasn't been released and hence either hasn't made it to Terraform yet or maybe in some Terraform beta component.

Comment: It's located on the monitoring alerting page https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting/policies
I want to add memory filter `state=used`.
I tried add to
```conditions {
  condition_threshold { filter = "metric.type=\"agent.googleapis.com/memory/percent_used\" AND resource.type=\"gce_instance\" AND state=\"used\""
```
but it gave an error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to add filter field `state=used` from terraform but i don't now what filed in terrform responsible for this.
[GCP page](https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/WIUI4aceLJta.png?o=1) and 
[terraform code](https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/GrqJULkyYanA.png?o=1)